# Connect a self-hosted WCF-Service via WebHttpBinding fails in Kerberos-Mode

Tags: c#, wcf, kerberos, webhttpbinding

I have a self-hosted WCF service that is accessible using `WebHttpBinding`. This service should get a kerberos token from the internet explorer on the client and then he should impersonate with this token to access an file server via a network share on an other server.

Like this chain:

```
IE (Client) -> WCF-Service (BI-Server) -> impersonate -> access network share on file server
```

But IE presents a login dialog if I change the `ClientCredentialType` or add an `ServiceAuthenticationBehavior` with Kerberos settings (401 Unauthorized).

With NTLM I can access the WCF service and impersonate but the access to the file server leads to an `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

The same server has also a `NetTcpBinding` with Kerberos which works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Delegation for Kerberos (all services) is activated on the BI server.

- ADS-Functional Level is 2012
- File server is a Windows Server 2003
- WCF/IIS-Host is a Windows Server 2012 R2
- Client is a Windows 8, IE 10

Now the code for the channel:

```
var listenUrl =  "http://0.0.0.0:8735";

var bind = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly)
{
         Security = {Transport = {ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.InheritedFromHost}},
         TransferMode = TransferMode.StreamedResponse
};

var host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(C_SIS), new Uri(listenUrl));
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IW_SIS), bind, "").Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

ServiceAuthenticationBehavior sab = null;
sab = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceAuthenticationBehavior>();
if (sab == null)
{
         sab = new ServiceAuthenticationBehavior();
         sab.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate | AuthenticationSchemes.Ntlm;
         host.Description.Behaviors.Add(sab);
}
else
{
         sab.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate | AuthenticationSchemes.Ntlm;
}

host.UnknownMessageReceived += new EventHandler<UnknownMessageReceivedEventArgs>(UnbekannterRecv);
host.Open();
```

Comment: Check if you have 'Enable Integrated Windows Authentication' settings checked in IE -> Settings -> Advanced -> Security

Comment: Is enabled and works in other usecases (like Intranet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, check that your service run with a Domain-User.
Then you must set an SPN (Service Principal Name) for this User.

```
setspn -s http\wcfHostMachineName:PORT DOAMIN\User
setspn -s http\wcfHostMachineName.FULLDomain.Quantifier:PORT DOAMIN\User
```

Clear all Kerberos-Tokens on your client with

```
klist -purge
```

Try it. If it works -> fine. But if not open your ADS-User-Configuration and delete all http-SPN's without port form the wcfHost, not the User! The wcfHost dosent need seperate SPN's.